# ReplaceAll not working as expected

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Still early days with Mathematica so please forgive what is probably a very obvious question. I am trying to generate some parametric plots. I have:

```
ParametricPlot[{
    (a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t],
    (a + b) Sin[t] - h Sin[(a + b)/b t]},
    {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All] /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1}
```

No joy: the replacement rules are not applied and `a`, `b` and `h` remain undefined.

If I instead do:

```
Hold@ParametricPlot[{
    (a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t],
    (a + b) Sin[t] - h Sin[(a + b)/b t]},
    {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All] /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1}
```

it looks like the rules ARE working, as confirmed by the output:

```
Hold[ParametricPlot[{(2 + 1) Cos[t] - 
1 Cos[(2 + 1) t], (2 + 1) Sin[t] - 1 Sin[(2 + 1) t]}, {t, 0, 
2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Which is what I'd expect. Take the `Hold` off, though, and the `ParametricPlot` doesn't work. There's nothing wrong with the equations or the `ParametricPlot` itself, though, because I tried setting values for a, b and h in a separate expression (`a=2; b=1; h=1`) and I get my pretty double cardoid out as expected.

So, what am I doing wrong with `ReplaceAll` and why are the transformation rules not working? This is another fundamentally important aspect of MMA that my OOP-ruined brain isn't understanding.

I tried reading up on `ReplaceAll` and `ParametricPlot` and the closest clue I found was that "`ParametricPlot` has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates `f` only after assigning specific numerical values to variables" which didn't help much or I wouldn't be here.

Thanks.

Comment: Hah! When you have a hammer, every problem starts to look like a nail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica evaluates each head without holding attributes by first evaluating head of each subexpression. Since ReplaceAll doesn't have holding attributes, `ParametricPlot` becomes `Graphics` before replacement

To see the expression tree, do

```
ParametricPlot[{(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - 
      h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
    PlotRange -> All] /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1} // Hold // TreeForm
```

From that tree you can see that your command is the same as doing

```
temp1=ParametricPlot[{(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - 
          h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
        PlotRange -> All]
temp2={a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1} 
temp1/.temp2
```

Look at `FullForm[temp1]` to confirm that there's no `a` or `b` in that expression.

If you set `ReplaceAll` to `HoldFirst`, that prevents ParametricPlot from being evaluated before `ReplaceAll`, and result is what you expected. In this case, `ReplaceAll` evaluates to expression with head `ParametricPlot`, and only at that point `ParametricPlot` is evaluated. Make sure to reset the attributes back because changing behavior of built-in commands can have unexpected side-effects.

```
SetAttributes[ReplaceAll, HoldFirst]; 
ParametricPlot[{(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - 
    h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotRange -> All] /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1}
ClearAttributes[ReplaceAll, HoldFirst]
```

A useful trick when needing to evaluate arguments passed to function with `HoldAll` is to do operations on an expression with `List` head, and substitute `ParametricPlot` in the end, for instance

```
ParametricPlot @@ ({{(a + b) Cos[t] - 
      h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}, {t, 0,
      2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All} /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation. I'll accept this as you've gone a little further than Belisarius, but I appreciate both.

Answer (score 3):

The best way for using local variables in Mathematica is `Module[]`:

```
Module[{a = 2, b = 1, h = 1}, 
   ParametricPlot[{(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}, 
   {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotRange -> All]]
```

This way a, b, and h do not get assigned values in the Global context but only inside the `Module`. If you still want to use replacement rules you just have to `ReleaseHold` after you have done the replacement:

```
ReleaseHold[
   Hold@ParametricPlot[{(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}, 
   {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotRange -> All] /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1}]
```

**EDIT:** As to why this happens. The way I understand it, `HoldAll` prevents the arguments of the function from being modified by *any* rules (internal or explicit). What your `Hold` does, is place the entire function on hold (not just the arguments), and the replacement rule gets applied *after* the function has gone through evaluation (which it didn't so there is still something there to replace) and `HoldAll` is no longer valid.

```
In[1]  := Hold[a /. a -> 5]
Out[1] := Hold[a /. a -> 5]
In[2]  := Hold[a] /. a -> 5
Out[2] := Hold[5]
```

Of course, `Hold` also has `HoldAll` as an attribute, so this doen't explain why `ParametricPlot`'s `HoldAll` is different. :-(

**EDIT2:** I used `Trace` to look at what happens, and it seems like `ReplaceAll` gets applied only at the very end, when `ParametricPlot` has already turned into a graphical object (and does not contain a, b, or h anymore). In the case of `Hold[a] /. a -> 5` the hold evaluates to `Hold[a]` and the replacement rule can then be successfully applied.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about `Module`, but I'd really like to know why `/.` isn't working here.

Comment: I prefer `With[]` to `Module[]` for things like these (I reserve `Module[]` and `Block[]` for routines), but I guess it's a stylistic point...

Answer (score 3):

That is the way ReplaceAll always work.

See for example:

```
In[10]:= (a/a) /. a -> 0

Out[10]= 1
```

Clearly the replacement is done AFTER the evaluation, because if you do:

```
In[11]:= a = 0; a/a

During evaluation of In[11]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[11]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>

Out[12]= Indeterminate
```

Now, is a matter of inserting the replacement at the level you want it to operate. As the result of a Plot is basically an Image with the numeric coordinates already "solved", you want to put those coordinates **in** before the plot is calculated. In your case:

```
ParametricPlot[
   {(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - h Sin[(a + b)/b t]} 
   /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1},
   {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 

 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, I see, that makes sense. Quite clear to me now when I read that together with Yaroslav's detailed explanation. I will have to think who to accept here :)

Comment: @Tim Feel free to accept whatever you want. The good thing is to come to a good and full answer as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer as such, just a comment on using Module with Plot.

If I proceed as follows

```
f[t_] := {(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - 
   h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}
```

The following will NOT work

Method 1:

```
Module[{a = 2, b = 1, h = 1}, 
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Method 2:

```
Module[{a = 2, b = 1, h = 1}, 
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[f[t]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

The following does work (Method 3)

```
ParametricPlot[
 Module[{a = 2, b = 1, h = 1}, Evaluate[f[t]]], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

as does the method described above (method 4)

```
Module[{a = 2, b = 1, h = 1}, 
   ParametricPlot[{(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}, 
   {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotRange -> All]]
```

Can anyone explain why method 4 works but method 2 doesn't?  (The same applies to With, which I find more intuitive to Module).

For what its worth, I would generate the original parametric plot using replacement rules as follows:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{(a + b) Cos[t] - h Cos[(a + b)/b t], (a + b) Sin[t] - 
     h Sin[(a + b)/b t]}] /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, h -> 1}, {t, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

EDIT

```
f[x_] := (a x)/(b + x);
With[{a = 10, b = 100}, Plot[Evaluate[f[x]], {x, 0, 100}]]
With[{a = 10, b = 100}, Plot[(a x)/(b + x), {x, 0, 100}]]
Plot[With[{a = 10, b = 100}, Evaluate[f[x]]], {x, 0, 100}]
Plot[Evaluate[f[x]] /. {a -> 10, b -> 100}, {x, 0, 100}]
```

Method 1 (of Edit) does not work (because 'Plot' treats the variable x as local, effectively using Block'?)

It seems to me that it is absolutely clear to anyone, even those with a rudimentary knowledge of Mathematica, what is going on with Method 2, showing the power and ease-of-use of Mathematica. When the equations become more complex, is it advantageous to define them separately.  It is now not so clear that Method 3 must be used instead of Method 1. (Method 4, of course, is probably the best of all.)

Comment: The **"a,b,c"** you define in the **Module[{a,b,c},** are **different variables** than those you define outside the Module construct. That's why it doesn't work: **scoping**

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for your comment.  I am aware of that the variables are different when defined in Module (and I am aware of scoping), but I cannot see why this makes a difference. Or at leasat I don't understand why.  Surely it is the behaviour of Plot that is at issue? I (now) read in the help that 'Plot treats the variable x as local, effectively using Block'. Is this not the explanation for why everything except method 1 in the edit works?

Comment: I didn't tried to imply you are unaware of scoping (sorry if my previous comment sounds "teachy"). Scoping is sometimes subtle, like in your case 1 in the edit. The problem is not the **x**, as it is used as a pattern in the function definition, but again the **a** and **b**. It's too clumsy to write it here in full in a comment without formatting. Perhaps you may post your edit as a question. I am sure you'll receive interesting answers.